# Not able to login with the different user in postgresql windows

Tags: postgresql

I have downloaded the binaries of postgresql for windows. I have to create a user name: root which has a database dbsum.

I created a database cluster with the command

```
C:\pgsql\bin>    initdb -U root -D C:\pgsql\data
```

and then I started the server:

```
C:\pgsql\bin>    pg_ctl.exe -D C:\pgsql\data -l C:\pgsql\log\pgsql.log start
```

After then, I tried to login :

```
C:\pgsql\bin>psql -U root
```

psql: FATAL:  database "root" does not exist

Then I tried to create the database root so that the above error could get resolved :

```
C:\pgsql\bin>  createdb root 

createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "sumit" does not exist
```

As per my understanding, its coming because I created the DB with 'root' and current user : 'sumit' does not have access to it as its role is not present.

Now the problem is, how do i create the the database root so that I can login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psql` assumes you want to connect to a database with the name of the current user.

```
psql -U root
```

will try to connect to a database named `sumit` if that is your current user. `initdb` creates  a default databased named `postgres`, which you can see from the output of the `initdb` command:

```
....
loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
vacuuming database template1 ... ok
copying template1 to template0 ... ok
copying template1 to postgres ... ok   <<--- this is the line
syncing data to disk ... ok
```

so what you really want is:

```
psql -U root  -d postgres
```

Comment: "`psql -U root` will try to connect to a database named `sumit` if that is your current user." - not true, it will try to connect to a database named after the specified user, `root` in this case.

Comment: Thanks man...my problem is resolved. I have 1 more query. If I try to connect to postgresql with sqldeveloper, it asks for the database root as my username is root. But I want to connect to database : 'dbsum' having a root user. Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: sqldeveloper problem also got resolved.. thanks for the reply

Comment: @SumitKhurana: sorry I don't use SQL Developer. Neither for Oracle nor for Postgres